# Discord.py | Youtube statistics

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, discord.py

How can I retrieve the information of an youtube account or video with a discord bot in python?

I want to do sth like this:

```
@commands.command(name='youtube', aliases=['yt'])
async def youtube(self, ctx, *, search):
    yt_object = youtube.search(search)
    if yt_object == channel:
        abonnements = yt_object.abonnements
        await ctx.send(abonnements)
    elif yt_object == video:
        views = yt_object.views
        await ctx.send(views)
```

Comment: I want to have the abonnements, channel or video name and if its a video the views
Would be very nice :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to utilise the Youtube Data API. You can find the documentation here: [Youtube Data API](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/youtube/v3/getting-started).

Once setup, you can use the `statistics` returned from a `channel.list` API call. Documentation for [Channel.list](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#forUsername)

Be aware that there is a daily quota that applies to retrieving channel stats.